# How to get all Filenames on Directory in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file, search, wildcard

I want to show all PDF filenames that has "33" in any position.

sample pdf list on PDFFiles Folder

```
1111.pdf
3311.pdf
2222.pdf
2331.pdf
1234.pdf
1233.pdf
```

I need to get result like this,that is something **like** wildcard **%33%** on sql

```
3311.pdf
2331.pdf
1233.pdf
```

I tried this one

```
Me.ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\PDFFiles", "*33*" & ".PDF", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

but it still displays all the pdf files.

```
1111.pdf
3311.pdf
2222.pdf
2331.pdf
1234.pdf
1233.pdf
```

and this

```
Me.ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("C:\PDFFiles", "*33" & ".PDF", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

but it only get

```
1233.pdf //this get all filename that ends with 33
```

Thanks in Regards

Comment: and why doesn't the top line of code work - enclosing wild card characters around the 33??? I can see why the bottom line only returns a sinlge file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern matching algorithm for wildcards are rather strange if you are used to regular expressions.  There's a lot of history behind it, going back through Windows 3, MS-DOS, CP/M (an operating system for 8-bit machines) and RSX (an operating system on 16-bit DEC machines).  With heavy borrowing between them, including the wildcard behavior.  Some accidental commonality btw, David Cutler was the principal architect behind the first and the last one.

Anyhoo, `*33*` isn't going to work.  You'll need to apply your own filter.  Search for `*.*` or `*.pdf` and use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension() and String.Contains() to find the matches.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed this behavior too when using more than one `*`.

I solved it by getting all file names and then filtering the correct names by using LINQ:

```
Dim allFileNames as String() = _ 
    Directory.GetFiles("C:\PDFFiles", "*.PDF", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim filtered As IEnumerable(Of String) = _ 
    .Where(Function(fileName) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Contains("33"))
```

Comment: Hi @Erno what object should i used in allFileNames and filtered ? I am using VB.NEt

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `*` at the end of `"*33"`, put one more star at the end of like `"*33*"`.

Your current expression : "*33" & ".PDF" means, All file names which ends with `33.PDF` that is why you are getting `1233.pdf` and not `2331.pdf`

EDIT:
[Directory.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx#Y1600)

> Search pattern similar to `"*1*.txt"` may return unexpected file names.
>   For example, using a search pattern of "*1*.txt" returns
>   "longfilename.txt" because the equivalent 8.3 file name format is
>   "LONGFI~1.TXT".

Comment: @BizApps, you have multiple GetFiles statements in your post, one on top should work, probably you are trying the 2nd one

Comment: @MD.UNicorn it displays all pdf file listed on my directory

Comment: @BizApps: We still insist that the first one on top of your post should work!

Comment: @BizApps, are you sure your filenames are not long names. Check the edit answer and the link, also add an extra back slash at the end of  `C:\PDFFiles\\` .

Comment: @MD.Unicorn i also thought that placing * on the end will work but still display all filenames but not the result that i want.

Answer (score 0):

We have found out that

Filter  `*___*`  works if the string has lenght greater than or equal to 4.

So if i want to get all records that has test name value:

```
test1234.pdf
abcdefg.pdf
123test45.pdf
12345678.pdf
```

My filter should be: `"*test" & ".PDF"` it will give the desired result

```
test1234.pdf
123test45.pdf
```

FYI